# Using PDO in PHP to count all from database and the 'WHERE' is a variable that has to be cleaned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I'm trying to count all of the rows from an item list where the id matches a user input. I am switching all of my code from mysql to PDO as I have learned it is much better.

The code below is what I found to work in my situation.

```
$id = '0';
$sql="SELECT count(*) FROM item_list WHERE item_id = $id";
$data=$connMembers->query($sql)->fetchcolumn();     
echo $data;
```

However, It is not safe for a live site due to sql injections.

I want to know how can I change it to work whare it sanatizes the user input.

I would prefer using a prepare and execute functions so the variables are kept seperately.

So is there something I can do?

Comment: yes, just check the documents for PDO, it is full of examples

Comment: there are numerous posts about how to sanitize with pdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you start binding parameters. I prefer to do it using `?` and one array for inputs.

Assuming `$connMembers` is your PDO object:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_list WHERE item_id = ?";
$input=array($id); //Input for execute should always be an array

$statement=$connMembers->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($input);
$data=$statement->fetchObject();

var_dump($data);
```

To add more variables to your sql, just add another `?` to the query and add the variable to your input.

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_list WHERE item_id = ? AND item_name=?";
$input=array($id, $name); //Input for execute should always be an array

$statement=$connMembers->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($input);
$data=$statement->fetchObject();

var_dump($data);
```

OR you can use bindParam:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item_list WHERE item_id = :itemID";

$statement=$connMembers->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':itemID', $id);
/*Here I am binding parameters instead of passing
an array parameter to the execute() */


$statement->execute();
$data=$statement->fetchObject();

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I fail to see where you are binding your Query

Comment: How do I get the values from the $data? The var_dump shows the appropriate content but I want to get just the number returned (the amount of rows in the table) -- I liked the above example, it was helpfull and it was clearified well.

Comment: Use $data->identifier. If the identifier has weird characters you should user $data->{'identifier'}. So in this case, `$data->{'COUNT(*)'}`.  The var_dump will tell you what the identifier is. If you like simple arrays better, change `fetchObject()` to `fetch()`

Comment: Thank You! That Helped/Cleared a lot. I will implement one or the other (depending on use) to all of my current mysql statements.